# How to write chunks of data in multiple csv files using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv

I am having some huge data like 100000 rows in a file and I want to write those data in CSV files but I want One CSV files that can contain only 20000 rows and the other 20000 rows write in another CSV file,

In this approach, I need 5 different CSV, each contains 20000 rows.
and the naming of the files should be.

```
csv_file1.csv
csv_file2.csv
csv_file3.csv
csv_file4.csv
csv_file5.csv
```

If data is 100001 so the last row should be written in another CSV file. The data limit of one CSV file is only 20000.

I have tried in this way:

```
while number_of_line != 20000:  
    with open(csv_file, 'w') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = defile_field
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in data:
            writer.writerow({"data":row})
```

Comment: You can divide the total by 2000 and round always up this way you know how many loops to run.

Comment: Thank you, I will try

Comment: still, I am getting some error

Comment: Does this answer help? [Automatically limit rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66642855/4985733)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a helper function like:

```py
import csv
from itertools import islice


def chunks(iterable, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from iterable."""
    it = iter(iterable)
    while chunk := tuple(islice(it, n)):
        yield chunk


data = [{"field_a": 1, "field_b": 2, "field_c": 3} for _ in range(15)]
fieldnames = ["field_a", "field_b", "field_c"]

for i, rows in enumerate(chunks(data, 10), start=1):
    with open(f"csv_file{i}.csv", "w") as csvfile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: Thanks for you code, but this code is not working properly, could you please help me out

Comment: Without at least one example of the data you're trying to feed it, it'll be hard :P

Comment: OK I added some test data and tested it, it works for Python >= 3.8, you'll have to rewrite the walrus to get it to work on old Pythons.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way is to use loop on the csv files getting data from the original one:

```
with open('orig.csv') as fd:
    rd = csv.DictReader(fd)
    num = 1
    cont = True
    while cont:
        with open('cvs_file{}.csv'.format(i), 'w', newline='') as fdout:
            wr = cvs.DictWriter(fdout, fieldnames=rd.fieldnames)
            wr.writeheader()
            for i in range(20000):       # max rows per file
                try:
                    row = next(rd)
                    wr.writerow(row)
                except StopIteration:
                    cont = False
                    break
        num += 1
```

Comment: Thanks you so much, but This code is give some error that the i is not defined.

Comment: @Shradha: My bad. I wrote `i` when it should have been `num`. Fixed.